# Pandas Read Nested Json Data

Tags: json, pandas

I have this JSON string:

```
{
    "2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z": [
        {
            "value": 0.216,
            "plantId": "27050937",
            "man": "pippo"
        },
        {
            "value": 0.224,
            "plantId": "30082443",
            "man": "pippo"
        }
    ],
    "2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z": [
        {
            "value": 0.248,
            "plantId": "27050937",
            "man": "pippo"
        },
        {
            "value": 0.108,
            "plantId": "30082443",
            "man": "pippo"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to import the data in order to build a numpy matrix indexed as (plantId, time).
For example, I would get a matrix like:

```
  300082443 0.216 0.108
  27050937  0.224 0.248
  ....
```

I tried with pandas:

```
a =pd.read_json("./data.json",orient='index')
```

But I get:

```
2022-09-28 00:45:00+00:00  {'value': 0.216, 'plantId': '27050937', 'man...  {'value': 0.224, 'plantId': '30082443', 'man...
2022-09-28 00:30:00+00:00  {'value': 0.248, 'plantId': '27050937', 'man...  {'value': 0.108, 'plantId': '30082443', 'man...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@jezrael's answer is much shorter and more efficient.**

Combining the two answers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{**{'date': k}, **x} for k, v in a.items() for x in v]) #jezrael's answer

df2=df.groupby('plantId')['value'].agg(list).reset_index()
df2[['value_1','value_2']] = pd.DataFrame(df2.value.tolist(), index= df2.index)
df2
'''
plantId           value  value_1  value_2
0  27050937  [0.216, 0.248]    0.216    0.248
1  30082443  [0.224, 0.108]    0.224    0.108
'''
```

details (long solution):

```
a={
    "2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z": [
        {
            "value": 0.216,
            "plantId": "27050937",
            "man": "pippo"
        },
        {
            "value": 0.224,
            "plantId": "30082443",
            "man": "pippo"
        }
    ],
    "2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z": [
        {
            "value": 0.248,
            "plantId": "27050937",
            "man": "pippo"
        },
        {
            "value": 0.108,
            "plantId": "30082443",
            "man": "pippo"
        }
    ]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(a)
```

df:
[image: df]

```
    2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z                                2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z
0   {'value': 0.216, 'plantId': '27050937', 'man': 'pippo'} {'value': 0.248, 'plantId': '27050937', 'man': 'pippo'}
1   {'value': 0.224, 'plantId': '30082443', 'man': 'pippo'} {'value': 0.108, 'plantId': '30082443', 'man': 'pippo'}
```

As the data increases, the number of columns will also increase. Now we need to convert these columns to rows.

```
df = df.T.reset_index() # T = transpose()
```

We used the [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) function to convert columns to rows.
latest version:
[image: latest version]

```
        index                       0                                       1
0       2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z    {'value': 0.216, 'plantId': '27050937', 'man': 'pippo'} {'value': 0.224, 'plantId': '30082443', 'man': 'pippo'}
1       2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z    {'value': 0.248, 'plantId': '27050937', 'man': 'pippo'} {'value': 0.108, 'plantId': '30082443', 'man': 'pippo'}
```

now let's parse the dictonary objects (columns 0 and 1) in the rows into new columns. We will use the [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) function for this.

```
first= pd.json_normalize(df.pop(0))
df=df.join(first)
second=pd.json_normalize(df.pop(1))
df = pd.concat([df,second])
print(df)
'''
                      index  value   plantId    man
0  2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z  0.216  27050937  pippo
1  2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z  0.248  27050937  pippo
0                       NaN  0.224  30082443  pippo
1                       NaN  0.108  30082443  pippo

'''
#if you want to fill NaNs use:
df = df.fillna({'index':df[['index']][df['index'].notnull()].squeeze()})
#fill nans with same index number.
'''
                      index  value   plantId    man
0  2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z  0.216  27050937  pippo
1  2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z  0.248  27050937  pippo
0  2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z  0.224  30082443  pippo
1  2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z  0.108  30082443  pippo
'''
```

json_normalize returns only the processed column values. But we also need other columns so we use [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) function. Then we should do the same operation in the column named 1. but here I am using [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) instead of join because the column names are the same and I want the data to be inserted one below the other (as rows not as columns). finally group by plant_id and add the values ​​to the list then split the list items into new columns.

```
df2=df.groupby('plantId')['value'].agg(list).reset_index()
df2[['value_1','value_2']] = pd.DataFrame(df2.value.tolist(), index= df2.index)
print(df2)
'''
    plantId           value  value_1  value_2
0  27050937  [0.216, 0.248]    0.216    0.248
1  30082443  [0.224, 0.108]    0.224    0.108
'''
```

Comment: thanks. but how to generalize the .pop instructions to N records?

Comment: true. I updated the answer, can you check it again?

Comment: ok. it looks quite hard for a newbie like me: could you point some references to doc or put some little explanation? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension for [`merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) `date`s  (outer keys) to nested dictionaries and pass to DataFrame constructor:

```
import json

with open('./data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  


df = pd.DataFrame([{**{'date': k}, **x} for k, v in data.items() for x in v])
print (df)
                       date  value   plantId    man
0  2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z  0.216  27050937  pippo
1  2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z  0.224  30082443  pippo
2  2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z  0.248  27050937  pippo
3  2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z  0.108  30082443  pippo
```

EDIT: Next step if need reshape DataFrame by `plantId` and `value` columns by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(g = df.groupby('plantId').cumcount().add(1))
         .pivot('plantId','g','value')
         .add_prefix('value'))
print (df1)
g         value1  value2
plantId                 
27050937   0.216   0.248
30082443   0.224   0.108
```

Or if need pivoting by `date` in columns:

```
df2 = df.pivot('plantId','date','value')
#df2 = df.pivot_table(index='plantId',columns='date',values='value', aggfunc='mean')
print (df2)
date      2022-09-28T00:30:00.000Z  2022-09-28T00:45:00.000Z
plantId                                                     
27050937                     0.248                     0.216
30082443                     0.108                     0.224
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, what's the purpose of putting `**` inside a a `dict`, please ?

Comment: @Stormy - it is oldier way for merge dictionaries

Comment: @Stormy - [`z = {**x, **y}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: good, but the answer is not completed because I need the matrix indexed by plantId

Comment: @gdm - extended solution in my answer.